# Same build definition for different branches

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, alm

Lets say I have the following branches for my application in TFS2012.
May2013 and June2013.

For deploying these applications I am using TWO different build definitions. One that points to the May20123.sln and one June2013.sln. The builds are doing the exact same thing, only difference pointing to different source code.

I would like to only have one build definition which starts with popup where I can choose which branch to deploy. Is this possible?

(This is just a simple example, the actual scenario is much more complex). I am aware that could change branching strategy...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible out of the box, but the `Clone build definition` feature if TFS 2012 should make your life a lot easier.  Simply, create a new branch and then clone an existing build.